# Go server returns corrupt image on arm64

Tags: go, arm64

I've written a simple HTTP image server:

go/src/demo/demo.go:

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/foobar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "/home/foobar/test.jpg")
  })

  http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
}
```

I compile it (PWD=$HOME/go/src/demo):

```
GOPATH=$PWD/../../ go build -o demo
```

And run:

```
./demo
```

Then in Chrome I open the URL. The image is corrupt -- reloading produces different corruption each time, once in a while it is fine. Larger images (~200KB) fail more often, smaller images (~20KB) fail less often.

Additional details:

`go version` produces `go version go1.9.5 linux/arm64`.

On my Macbook, this causes no issues -- only occurs on arm64 (looks like ResponseWriter does not implement flushing). I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with the go1.9.5 release. Updated toolchain to go1.10.1 and the issue disappeared.

Comment: There is no problem at all with the release 1.9.5. Tested and working (without external libraries). Maybe that is the problem, but not go.

Comment: Which architecture and device did you test on? The above code (even using `http.NewServeMux()` instead of gorilla) when compiled with https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.1.linux-arm64.tar.gz, works as expected, but when compiled with https://dl.google.com/go/go1.9.5.linux-arm64.tar.gz, exhibits the corruption described above.

Comment: Debian stretch, [containerized](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/97535d47a7c8312b25fc98418771f943c0bbdfb3/1.9/stretch/Dockerfile). Works with no problem.

Comment: I mean architecture as in are you running on arm64 (not amd64)? I suspect this only affects arm64.